# SHA-1 producing different results in Objective-C and PHP... ideas?

Tags: php, ios, encryption, passwords, sha1

I'm currently having this issue where a data API provider is requesting SHA-1 hashed passwords when communicating through an iOS app. It works about 95% of the time but some special characters are causing a lot of headaches.

Here's the password that yields different results **ABjnxQ^Lx2%f8vb**

From http://www.sha1.cz/ --> **48518a5be263c7a222f4863b66889019aa272191**

From http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/sha1/ --> **b9b50de32d1bce1827a8e9d60ddbf4e0545fcb68**

The second one is what my ObjC function returns too. However the PHP SHA1() the API provider uses gets the first one. I have narrowed it down to the fact that there is a `%` sign in this sample. Anyone has any wisdom related to this?

Here is my Objective-C function:

```
- (NSString *)hashPassword:(NSString *)pass {
    const char *cstr = [pass cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:pass.length];

    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_SHA1(data.bytes, data.length, digest);

    NSMutableString *output = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

    return output;
}
```

Before you suggest encoding, please note I've tried changing the encoding type to ASCII, UTF8, 16, 32, and most of the other encoding types in `NSStringEncoding` enum in `NSString.h`.

Could someone offer an explanation or advice on how to fix this please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: When I use the php sha1 function I get `b9b50de32d1bce1827a8e9d60ddbf4e0545fcb68` and I believe this is the correct one as all of the sha1 hash sites that I googled give this and SQL server and mysql give this as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that http://www.sha1.cz interprets `%nn` as percent escape and http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/sha1/ not. For example:

- http://www.sha1.cz computes the hash of "%30" as `b6589fc6ab0dc82cf12099d1c2d40ab994e8410c`.
- http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/sha1/
  computes the hash of "0" as the same value `b6589fc6ab0dc82cf12099d1c2d40ab994e8410c`.

So the first site interprets "%30" as "0", which makes sense because the ASCII-code of "0" is `0x30`.

But such a "percent-escape decoding" does not make much sense for an arbitrary
password string. And for "%f8" is is unclear which encoding is used to remove
the percent escape.

So my conclusion would be: `b9b50de32d1bce1827a8e9d60ddbf4e0545fcb68`
is the *correct* answer. To get the same answer from http://www.sha1.cz,
you have to replace each "%" character by "%25", and voilà:

- http://www.sha1.cz computes the hash of "ABjnxQ^Lx2%25f8vb" as `b9b50de32d1bce1827a8e9d60ddbf4e0545fcb68`

which is what the second service and your Objective-C code computed.

Replacing "%" by "%25" (for http://www.sha1.cz) can be done with the `NSString`
method `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this seems to be buggy php hash function. I agree - a percent % sign is source of trouble for PHP SHA1 function.
Just for my curiosity - I tried other, non PHP online tools (http://www.sha1-online.com/) to find out SHA1 hash for given password:

ABjnxQ^Lx2%f8vb

and it is:

b9b50de32d1bce1827a8e9d60ddbf4e0545fcb68

I don't want to complain about poorly designed PHP 'language' but try to read this [article: PHP: a fractal of bad design](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/). Have a fun!